# Hazard ratio plot with confidence "waist" in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, spline, survival-analysis

When fitting a cox model that includes spline terms for a continuous covariate, I would like to be able to produce a plot of the hazard ratio across range of that covariate (relative to a fixed reference value) using ggplot2.

I have adapted an example from Terry Therneau's splines vignette [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/splines.pdf) (see page 3). The only issue with this approach is the lack of a "waist" in the confidence interval at the reference value, as in this plot:

[image]

The example below produces the following plot, without the narrowing of the CI at the reference value.

```
library(survival)
library(splines)
library(ggplot2)

# colon cancer death dataset
ccd <- na.omit(subset(colon, etype == 2))

# fit model with ns() term for age
cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ rx + sex + ns(age, knots = c(20, 50, 70)), data = ccd)

# get data for plot
tp <- termplot(cox, se = TRUE, plot = FALSE)

# hazard ratio plot for natural spline of age, with reference @ 50 yrs
ref <- tp$age$y[tp$age$x == 50]

ggplot() +

  geom_line(data = tp$age, aes(x = x, y = exp(y - ref))) + 
  geom_line(data = tp$age, aes(x = x, y = exp(y - 1.96 * se - ref)), linetype = 2) + 
  geom_line(data = tp$age, aes(x = x, y = exp(y + 1.96 * se - ref)), linetype = 2) +

  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 1), linetype = 3) +

  geom_rug(data = ccd, aes(x = age), sides = "b") +

  labs(x = "Age at baseline, years",
       y = "Hazard Ratio (95% CI) vs. 50 years",
       title = "Mortality hazard ratio as a function of age",
       subtitle = "Natural spline: knots at 20, 50, and 70 years")
```

[image]

I am aware that there are features in the `rms` package and the `smoothHR`package that produce these types of plots, but I am looking for a solution that is amenable to `ggplot2` graphics and the `coxph()` function in the `survival` package. My question therefore boils down to:

- Is there a way to adapt the output of `termplot()` to produce a plot with a "waist" at the reference value?
- If `termplot()` cannot be used, how can I obtain the relevant plotting data by other means?

---

**Edit 1:** As the first comment suggested, this can be accomplished using `rms` and `ggplot2` together. For example:

```
    library(rms)
dd <- datadist(ccd)
dd$limits$age[2] <- 50
options(datadist = "dd")

cph <- cph(Surv(time, status) ~ rx + sex + rcs(age, c(20, 50, 70)), data = ccd, x = TRUE, y = TRUE)

pdata <- Predict(cph, age, ref.zero = TRUE, fun = exp)

ggplot(data = pdata) +

  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 1), linetype = 3) +

  labs(x = "Age at baseline, years",
       y = "Hazard Ratio (95% CI) vs. 50 years",
       title = "Mortality hazard ratio as a function of age",
       subtitle = "Natural spline: knots at 20, 50, and 70 years")
```

Which produces a plot very close to what I am after:

[image]

However, **I would still like to know if there is a way to do this using `coxph()` and `ns()`**. Not that I have anything against the `rms` package, I just have a bunch of old code based on `survival`functionality.

Comment: I thought there were ggplot2 options for plotting in rms? I know that a couple of years ago that package began importing ggplot2.